# ext3 will trim be supported?

Tags: debian, linux, debian-squeeze

Current linux kernel version supports trim however Debian Squeeze uses an old version that does not.

As I understand, the trim support is in the linux kernel itself and not a specific filesystem. Therefore, will ext3 support trim in the new kernel? If it does not, will it support it in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All layers of the storage stack have to support trim. After all only file system layer knows, which blocks are safe to be wiped.

[This](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.ext4/22890) post on the ext4 developers list with patch for elements of trim functionality in ext3 strongly suggest that such work is being done already.

Answer (score 0):

The fstrim command is present in Fedora 15....

Kernel version  2.6.41.4-1.fc15.x86_64.

Package: util-linux-2.19.1-1.4.fc15.x86_64.rpm